# Network Error when export zip file

Tags: export

I implement a function to allow users to download multiple selected files as one zip file. I use Ionic.Zip library for this function. On my local machine, there is no problem, works well on Firefox, Chrome and IE; however there is problem when it is on test server at any web browsers, which has separate database, app and web front server. The file will throws Network error when download progress is nearly finished. This is code block I use for this function

```
            response.Clear();
            response.BufferOutput = false;

            System.Web.HttpContext c = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
                filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss");
            string archiveName = String.Format("archive-{0}.zip", filename);
            response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + archiveName + "\"");
            try
            {
                using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                    {
                        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                        {
                            if (item.ContentType.Name != "Folder")
                            {
                                var file = item.File;
                                var content = file.OpenBinary(SPOpenBinaryOptions.None);
                                zip.AddEntry(file.Name, content);
                            }
                        }
                        zip.Save(ms);
                    }
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", ms.Length.ToString());
                    ms.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
```

I then try placing `response.End()` just after `using(MemoryStream){}`, then the problem happens with Chrome. Firefox and IE are ok. If I debug into this function, it will return file without problem. It is quite strange.

I have tried changing mime type for .zip in IIS, but failed for Chrome, Firefox and IE works well even though sometimes the file might be corrupt.
Please give me advice.

Update: This is the output when I set the Response.BufferOutput = true.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most certainly due to the `BufferOutput = false` and IIS disconnections with client.

1. Test with `BufferOutput = true` (i.e. default for ASP.NET).
2. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600856/how-to-deliver-big-files-in-asp-net-response and apply some of the solutions proposed by Akash Kava.
3. Also, [the answer from Aristos in the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601866/3439544) contains very relevant information for you.

Comment: I have updated the code block as your suggestion, but not work. I have also updated the error in the post.